# How can I generate several instances of a single class that have unique instance names that remain accessible in the global scope in python?

Tags: python, oop, automation

```
Class Obj():

    self.var1
    self.var2

    def populate_attributes(self):
        # a function that gets values for the instance variables

# list of objects names that will be populated from an external source ie. Spreadsheet or list of folders etc.
list_of_object_names = ["first_instance", "second_instance", "third_instance"]

For item in list_of_object_names:
    # create instance of Obj() with value of item
```

Can someone tell me how this is accomplished? I want to be able access the instance attributes and methods without having to iterate through a list as there will be lots of instances in my finished project. Above is only for the sake of explanation. I have a way to generate the list of names but how can I use those as the instance variables names them selves so I can use them:

```
print(first_instance.var1, second_instance.var1) # for example
```

I have done some reading but the articles/posts don't seem to offer the solution I am looking for. Is what I am asking possible?

Comment: If you actually know that your code snippets are not real `python`, you should update your question with real code. If you don't know what real `python` is, you will need to do some research/training before you can ask a question.

Comment: @quamrana This code is for basic illustration and I typed it out from my phone. To avoid confusion I will correct the syntax in my snippet

Comment: It would be better to have all these objects instances and there names in a dict or list so you can handle them more easily. If you have more than 10 objects or variable number of objects this is a Must.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there is a method for doing this, but I recommend NEVER using it. NEVER, because it's very ugly and not at all Pythonic.

Instead, I think you can create these instances in a `dict`, like this...

```py
instances = {name: Obj() for name in list_of_object_names}
```

This is a dictionary comprehension. It iterates over each element (which we assume to be a name or identifier) in list_of_object_names, and for each name, it creates a key-value pair in the resulting dictionary.

- name is the key: It's one of the names from list_of_object_names.
- Obj() is the value: It's an instance of an object created by calling the Obj() constructor.

So, the end result is a dictionary where the keys are taken from list_of_object_names, and the values are objects created by calling the Obj() constructor.

If I rewrite all your code, it will become :

```py
class Obj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 0
        self.var2 = 0
    def populate_attributes(self):
        pass

list_of_object_names = ["first_instance", "second_instance", "third_instance"]
instances = {name: Obj() for name in list_of_object_names}

print(instances["first_instance"].var1, instances["second_instance"].var1)
```

I don't think it's what you expected, but it should be enough. I think, without vanity, I know enough about python to assure you that what you want is not the right way to learn python.

However, for the science, here is the **forbidden** technique :

`globals()` is a dict who can work as the precedent method...
So :

```py
class Obj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 0
        self.var2 = 0
    def populate_attributes(self):
        pass

list_of_object_names = ["first_instance", "second_instance", "third_instance"]
for name in list_of_object_names:
    globals()[name] = Obj()

print(first_instance.var1, second_instance.var1)
```

Once again: **don't use this technique**